# Binding data without disturbing UI using windows phone 7.1

Tags: windows-phone-7

I am new the WP7.1. I am developing chat app, in that there is screen like friends, in that screen it like 1000s of friends are there, We are binding to longlistselector the using sqlite.

Main problem is like, we have one API for calling friend's update like (displayname, profile picture etc) and I am processing the API data and binding the data to longlistselector, at the time of binding, I am not able to scroll the longlistselecor and any other buttons in the screen.

I am binding the data using Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => { Binding to }); and Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => { Binding to }) and BackgroundWorker (I tried those many ways).

Please suggest any solutions binding the without disturbing UI.

Thanks in advance.

-- Chandra

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you push data on the screen (be it through XAML {Binding} or through directly accessing the page's UI elements) it needs to be done on the UI thread. While the UI thread is busy with processing your code or with redrawing the UI because of your code, the UI freezes.

This means that you need to make everything inside BeginInvoke() as short and efficient as possible. However you also need to make as few calls to BeginInvoke() as possible. Finding the balance between these will determine the experienced speed of your UI.

In the case of LongListSelector I found that it's efficient to add 50 items at a time, wait half a second and add the next 50 items. Your mileage may vary.

Comment: Oh. I thought it was "1000s of friends". However: Move all API calls and processing on a background thread. Only have the minimum required code in BeginInvoke(). Simplify the ItemTemplate's XAML (or update your question with both code and XAML).